# Vue.js asyncronous components, named import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I know how to load asynchronous component in Vue. This

```
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent'

export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
}
```

is replaced like

```
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent: () => import('@/components/MyComponent')
  }
}
```

But how can I replace "named" component import, like this?

```
import { SweetModal } from 'sweet-modal-vue'

export default {
  components: {
    SweetModal
  }
}
```

How do I import that asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use at the same way, but getting your specific component:

```
export default {
  components: {
    SweetModal: () => import('sweet-modal-vue').then(m => m.SweetModal)
  }
}
```

I recommend you to read this:  [Async Vue.js Component](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/async-vuejs-components/)

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sweet-modal-vue/SweetModal'

Comment: @mthrsj no error until I want to actually open that modal by calling `this.$refs.myModal.open()`. This works with static import.

Comment: @appleapple resolve is the solution. I made it a bit cleaner. Your solution also requires also resolve(). Solution that now works is `SweetModal: () => import('sweet-modal-vue').then(m => m.SweetModal)`. I have updated the answer!