# Nuxt Local import component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, lazy-initialization

I want to use `vue2-editor` (and some other packages) in my project, but use them local inside component or two. I followed this thread [How to use plugin in only one component using Nuxt.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298099/how-to-use-plugin-in-only-one-component-using-nuxt-js/69307486#69307486) but the solution doesn't help me, I see the following error

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Please suggest what I am missing?

Template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
   <client-only>
      <vue-editor v-model="newIdea.description" />
   </client-only>
  </div>
</template>
```

Components:

```js
components: {
 [process.client && 'VueEditor']: () => import('vue2-editor')
}
```

Is this somehow related that I should `import {VueEditor} from 'vue2-editor'` and not directly `'vue2-editor'`?
I also tried to add .default but it didn't help.

Bottom line that import {VueEditor} from 'vue2-editor' is working and  [process.client && 'VueEditor']: () => import('vue2-editor') is not (all the rest code is same, so definitely something wrong with the second import, but what? Or maybe I missed something?)

Comment: @kissu maybe you could take a look?

Comment: Hm, you may need a wrapping `div` (around your `client-only`) here.

Comment: Because otherwise, it means that the server have no node to SSR, which may be be confusing for the compiler (which expect at least something).

Comment: @kissu no it's not the case, actually I had outer div, just didn't put here in example..any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you comment this part of code just to be sure that the issue is coming from this and not something else? Also, do you have a [repro] or a public Github repo?

Comment: it doesn't work for me for other packages as well, let say import { Money } from "v-money" works, but [process.client && "Money"]: () => import("v-money") doesn't with all other code the same..maybe I missed smth?

Comment: Same with vue2-editor: 
import { VueEditor } from "vue2-editor"; + components { VueEditor } 
WORKS (on client mode, without, reload), 
[process.client && "VueEditor"]: () => import("vue2-editor") throw an error. 

I don't have github repo for this issue, just faced it today..

Comment: I found the solution! Was exactly what I suspect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55378794/vue-js-asyncronous-components-named-import